# jQuery and input forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this input form with Name and Text.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="main">
    <label>Write a comment!</label><br>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="form-text" name="user" type = "text" id = "user" autofocus size = "48"><br/>
    <textarea class="form-text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="new_comment" value="Submit comment">
</form>
```

and I added some `jQuery` for this form.

```
$(".form-submit").click(function() {
    var commentBox = $("#comment");
    var userBox = $("#user");

    var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
    var userCheck = userBox.val();

    if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == NULL ) {
        commentBox.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(commentBox);
        return false;
    }   

    if (userCheck == '' || userCheck == NULL){
        userBox.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(userBox);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And now I'm here with this problem. I want the user to fill both fields in order to write a comment (`name & text`). For any empty fields I want to add class `"form-text-error"` . Everything works except for field with users name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "_I want the user to fill **both fields** in order to write a comment_" You don't have two fields which you will fill to allow the comment, you just have a username and a comment fields. Or you meant to say **"in order to POST ...."**

Answer (score 1):

Use `Length` to get length of `input` then if return zero do `addClass`

```js
$(".form-submit").click(function() {
  var commentBox = $("#comment");
  var userBox = $("#user");

  var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
  var userCheck = userBox.val();



  if (commentCheck.length <= 0 || commentCheck == NULL) {
    commentBox.addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(commentBox);
    return false;
  }

  if (userCheck.length <= 0 || userCheck == NULL) {
    userBox.addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(userBox);
    return false;
  }



});
```

```css
.form-text-error {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="main">
  <label>Write a comment!</label><br>
  <input placeholder="Name" class="form-text" name="user" type="text" id="user" autofocus size="48"><br/>
  <textarea class="form-text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="new_comment" value="Submit comment">
</form>
```

Also you can use `submit` function instead of `click`:

```
$(".form-submit").submit(function() {});
```

But i recommend you to use something like this:

```
$(".form-submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //remove this later
  $('.form-text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
      $(this).addClass('form-text-error');
      return false;
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('form-text-error');
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but now i can send the form with both fields empty :D

Comment: @TomsEglite `return false` cause of this. try my rewrited code, and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

it is due to condition if return with false so it will check 1st condition and return back no further check.
need to make changes accordingly as below.

```
$(".form-submit").click(function() {
    var commentBox = $("#comment");
    var userBox = $("#user");

    var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
    var userCheck = userBox.val();
    var err = false;


    if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == NULL ) {
        commentBox.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(commentBox);
        err = true;
    }   

    if (userCheck == '' || userCheck == NULL){
        userBox.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(userBox);
        err = true;
    }
if(err)
return false;


});
```

Comment: Still the same thing happens.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did not check the code properly. Now it kinda works, i managed to add form-error-class to both fields, but anyway, i can send the form even with one field empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing return false after comment

```
if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == NULL ) {
        commentBox.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(commentBox);
        return false;
    }
```

That's why it didn't get name field
You can use like this as like your requirement,

```
var commentBox = $("#comment");
var userBox = $("#user");
var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
var userCheck = userBox.val();
var flag =0;
if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == NULL ) {
    $("#comment").addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(commentBox);
    flag = 1;
}   
if (userCheck == '' || userCheck == NULL){
    $("#user").addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(userBox);
    flag = 1;
}
if(flag == 1)return false;
```

Comment: This is the same solution as @Komal suggested me to do. Now I can add a class to both fields if they are empty, but I still can send the form even if one field is empty.

Comment: Then use this snippet, it will return false for any empty input fields..
var commentBox = $("#comment");
var userBox = $("#user");
var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
var userCheck = userBox.val();
var flag =0;
var flag1 =0;
if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == NULL ) {
    $("#comment").addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(commentBox);
    flag = 1;
}   
if (userCheck == '' || userCheck == NULL){
    $("#user").addClass("form-text-error");
    console.log(userBox);
    flag1 = 1;
}
if(flag == 1 || flag1==1)return false;

Comment: Even after this code I can still send the form even with one empty field.. this is pain in the ass. :D

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false for both the validations.
Also, use `.length === 0  || !box`.
A common function would help.

**Fixed**

use `e.preventDefault();` This would validate the username field as well and would not submit if empty.

```js
var commentBox = $("#comment");
var userBox = $("#user");
   
function checkIfEmpty(box, check) { 
    if (check.length === 0  || !box) {
        box.addClass("form-text-error");
        console.log(box);
        return true;
    } else {
        box.removeClass("form-text-error");
        return false;
    }
 }
    
$(".form-submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
    var userCheck = userBox.val();
    var commentCall = checkIfEmpty(commentBox, commentCheck);
    var userCall =  checkIfEmpty(userBox, userCheck);
    if(userCall === true && commentCall === true) {
      return false;
    }
});
```

```css
.form-text-error {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="main">
    <label>Write a comment!</label>
    <br/>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="form-text" name="user" type="text" id="user" autofocus size="48"/>
    <br/>
    <textarea class="form-text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="new_comment" value="Submit comment"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It adds the text error class, but i can still send the input to my db with one field empty. I' m starting to think that there could be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Fixed the code. Now, the form won't submit if name field is empty.

Comment: Copied the code, it gets this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at checkIfEmpty (global.js:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (global.js:29)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`

Comment: The snippet is working fine. I think it's related to the variable scope. Try declaring `var commentBox = $("#comment");
var userBox = $("#user");` variables as global.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use input type="button" and use this snippet that's tested and it works...
$("#comment").removeClass("form-text-error");
        $("#user").removeClass("form-text-error");
        var commentBox = $("#comment");
        var userBox = $("#user");
        var commentCheck = commentBox.val();
        var userCheck = userBox.val();
        var flag =0;
        var flag1 =0;
        if(commentCheck == '' || commentCheck == null ) {
            $("#comment").addClass("form-text-error");
            console.log(commentBox);
            flag = 1;
        }   
        if (userCheck == '' || userCheck == null){
            $("#user").addClass("form-text-error");
            console.log(userBox);
            flag1 = 1;
        }
        if(flag == 1 || flag1 == 1){return false;}
        else{return true;}
```